# Find limit using generalized binomial theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to prove that
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\left|\frac{(x+y)^\beta\sin\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right| = 0
$$

For every $\beta >1$. So I'm trying to use that

$$
\left|\frac{(x+y)^\beta\sin\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right| \leq \frac{(x+y)^\beta}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
$$

And when I put the right limit in WolframAlpha with $\beta$ near to $1$, always returns that the limit is $1$ so I guess it could be true for every $\beta >1$. But I don't know how to prove it . I've tried to use some kind of [generalization of the binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Generalizations) to generalize the argument given here

[image]

But I haven't been able to do it yet. Any hints or counterexample?

Comment: Your idea is fine, we can conclude by polar coordinates $$\frac{\left|x+y\right|^\beta}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} =\rho^{\beta -1}\left|\cos \theta + \sin \theta\right|^{\beta}\to 0$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have exactly the right idea! As a life-pro-tip, one common way to simplify estimates like these is to try to get all of our norms to look similar. Here we have a $|x+y|$ in the numerator (which looks like an $L^1$-norm) and we have a $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ in the denominator (an $L^2$-norm). In order to simplify our expression, we want to have only one kind of norm (if possible) so that things will cancel. Thankfully, there's a standard way of converting between our norms (at least in the finite dimensional case):

By [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) we know

$$|x+y| = | \langle 1, 1 \rangle \cdot \langle x,y \rangle  | \leq \sqrt{1^2 + 1^2} \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = \sqrt{2} \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

So up to a factor of $\sqrt{2}$, we can cash out the $|x+y|$ norm for a $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ norm, which will cancel with the denominator!

$$
\frac{|x+y|^\beta}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \leq 
\frac{\left (\sqrt{2} \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \right )^\beta}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} =
\sqrt{2}^\beta \left ( x^2+y^2 \right )^{\frac{\beta - 1}{2}}
$$

Now since $\beta > 1$, the exponent on $x^2 + y^2$ is positive, so the right hand side goes to $0$, as desired.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: I really appreciate your life-pro tip! I am a undergraduate cs student and your blog really inspires me. virtual hug 